# Using Laravel Scout database driver, where does it store the indexes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I was trying out Laravel Scout's database driver and I am wondering how it works behind the scene. Where does it store the indices and how does it perform the searches?

Answer (score 0):

It is running "WHERE LIKE" clauses. Indexes are not stored anywhere, so you may want to add an index to you database using migration:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->fullText(['title', 'content']);
});
```